# JavaScript map files in Firefox not working

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox, bundling-and-minification

I deploy an application with JQuery, Bootstrap, etc, using minified javascript files, including map files.  The map files are located in the same directory as the mini.js files and the mini.js files correctly point to the maps.

This is doing something but what it's doing is not what I'd hoped for.  Instead of showing xxx.min.js in the droplist of scripts, it's showing xxx.js which would be fine except there is a 400 error on retrieving this non-existent file.

If I remove the map file, then xxx.min.js shows up in the droplist of scripts, and shows the compressed source.

And this behavior occurs, by the way, in both Firebug and the Firefox debugger.

I've tried installing the JavaScript Deminifier plugin for Firefox and this seems to work sometimes and not others.  It seems more like a hack than a solution as what it renders when it's working is a "beautified" approximation of what the uncompressed file should be rather than the file uncompressed "officially" by an explicit map.

What am I missing as far as getting map files to work properly?

Answer (score 0):

What has happened is that the comment is read by firefox. It wants to load the map file with source instead of the min file. I haven't looked if someone submitted a bug report.

I'm running 4beta and on the last line of bootstrap.bundle.min.js has the map file comment. If you delete the line, it remove this the error.

I don't know why they put the map file comment on packages that people are going to deploy. you only need that to edit the min file, which in production, you are not going to do that.